# How to enable high availability in JanusGraph?

Tags: janusgraph

I have the problem of enabling high availability in JanusGraph, that is, enabling several clusters in the same Janus... I have searched many bibliographies, and I have not been able to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take the [advanced JanusGraph deployment scenario](https://docs.janusgraph.org/operations/deployment/#advanced-scenario) and add an open source load balancer  in front, such as https://www.haproxy.org/.